# Define multiple names for a single Meteor server method

Tags: meteor, meteor-methods

I have a Meteor package that exports several server methods. Since there's no widespread convention on how a method should be named, I want to make more than one names for each method. At first, I used calls to the first method from other ones:

```
Meteor.methods({
    a: function () {
        return 'something';    
    },
    b: function () {
        return Meteor.call('a');
    }
});
```

Now I use a simpler approach:

```
const something = function () {
    return 'something';
};

Meteor.methods({
    a: something,
    b: something
});
```

But is there even simpler, or maybe even conventional, approach to do that?

Comment: Your simple approach is fine.

Comment: Never seen anything simpler than that